# Which preposition to use - for or of?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should below sentence use and why?

In the given chart, we can observe cellular phone sales for four companies OR

In the given chart, we can observe cellular phone sales of four companies.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Your question is not answerable in its current state. Neither of your choices is a sentence. You have not told us what situation you are trying to describe, and word choice and meaning will be dependent on context. Please see *[Please, everyone… details.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439)* for some guidelines on the information that will help us provide informed answers, and if you are new to Stack Exchange, I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: Thank u. I've now corrected the description.

Comment: Although it's not strictly incorrect, I object to your usage of 'below' as an adjective. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609/which-is-correct-the-below-information-or-the-information-below.

Comment: It would be good to know what you've done to try to work this out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct, but the second sentence has a mistake in it.  If you want to use "of", you need to add "the":

> In the given chart, we can observe **the** cellular phone sales of four companies.

If you want to improve these sentences further in terms of style, you might want to change "In the given chart, we can observe ..." to "The given chart shows ...."  This is less wordy and therefore stronger.

Also, stylistically, "The given chart" sounds slightly awkward to my ear.  "The chart below," "The chart above," or "The attached chart" would be better.  I would therefore recommend:

> The chart below shows cellular phone sales for four companies.

or:

> The chart below shows the cellular phone sales of four companies.

I have a slight preference for the latter, since there is some ambiguity in the former as to who is doing the selling.

Comment: Welcome to English language learners. I'm not sure you are really clearly answering the question that was asked. The questioner asked which preposition to use and why, and you spend more time discussing entirely different wording. In essence you are saying "either version is fine, but I prefer the second", but you don't specifically say that anywhere. So I would perhaps edit to say that very clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will try to make my answer more clear.

Answer (score -1):

Your first example is acceptable and quite common, with 'for' meaning 'with respect to' or 'concerning'.

Your second example is more correct, with 'of' meaning 'relating to' or 'belonging to'.